# Bad substitution error from within sh file

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins

As part of my Jenkins pipeline I use an environmental variable.

This works fine:

```
sh "docker build --build-arg aws_access=${env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID} ...."
```

However we are refactoring and now we need to use the variable from within an sh file.

We execute the .sh file like this in the jenkins file:

```
sh('./bin/someFile.sh')
```

inside of that file we do:

```
#!/bin/bash
    .... some unrelated stuff .....
docker build --build-arg aws_access=${env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID} ....
```

The Jenkins build fails:

> ./bin/someFile.sh: line 6: aws_access=${env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}: bad
> substitution

I have been googling this issue and following all advices I found here in SO and elsewhere. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need the `env.` prefix when using Bash - you refer to the environment variable directly:

```sh
docker build --build-arg aws_access=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
```

Bash variables are vastly different from Jenkins ones, and what's more, with your Jenkins script, the shell doesn't see those "variables", as Jenkins has already substituted them for the values.